# Error installing Sitecore 9.3 - IdentityServer_InstallWDP

Tags: installation, identity-server

I tried to install a `local` environment using `Sitecore 9.3` and got error on final step, when checking logs it seems that there's an error concerning the `IdentityServer` deployment

```
[------- IdentityServer_SetPermissions : FilePermissions ---------------------]
[IdentityServer_SetPermissions]:[Allow] IIS AppPool\GDT_SC93identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_SetPermissions]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\GDT_SC93identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_SetPermissions]:[Rights] FullControl
System.Object[]
[IdentityServer_SetPermissions]:[Propagate] None

[----------- IdentityServer_InstallWDP : WebDeploy ---------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1073741819)
[TIME] 00:00:16
Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1073741819)
```

Any suggestion to fix the problem ?
Tx

Comment: Can you please run the PS1 developer script to uncover more readable and descriptive error message. Also, can you please check if you are running the Graphical SIA in Administrator mode.

Comment: Any Update on this query ? I am also facing similar issue but with Sitecore 10.x installation.

Comment: Can you check in your logs if you are getting the error something like this? `File system path 'GDT_SC93identityserver.dev.local' is not valid` ?

Comment: Also Please try this https://firstlightsalon.in/sitecore_threads/questions/23244/webdeploy-unable-to-deploy-package

Comment: can you check WebPlatformDownload link is working. if not update as below config in prerequisites.json
"WebPlatformDownload": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Download location of Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0",
            "DefaultValue": "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-direct-downloads"
        },